# Gradle: publish existing jar/source/javadoc to maven

Tags: java, eclipse, gradle, jar

I have some proprietary libraries which are used in my java project. I use gradle as build manager. I use the eclipse-ide.
Since I dont want to have any binaries in my repo, I created a custom maven repository. Prior to Gradle 6.x Gradle just downloaded the .jar file with the correct folder structure in the repository (GROUPNAME/ARTIFACT/VERSION/... .jar)
After I updated to Gradle 6.5 Gradle wanted a .pom file to specify the jar. So I created a dummy project with this build file and used the command **gradle install** to get the .pom file.

```
plugins {
    id 'java-library'
    id 'maven'
}

repositories {
    jcenter()
}

dependencies {
    api group: 'commons-codec', name: 'commons-codec', version: '1.10'
    api group: 'commons-logging', name: 'commons-logging', version: '1.2'
    api group: 'org.slf4j', name: 'slf4j-api', version: '1.7.25'
    api group: 'log4j', name: 'log4j', version: '1.2.17'
}

install {
    repositories.mavenInstaller {
        pom.version = '...'
        pom.groupId = '...'
        pom.artifactId = '...'
    }
}
```

With this method I had to rename the library jar accordingly. Now I have the .pom file but missing all the md5/sha/metafile/... files which are normaly generated with the maven-publish plugin.

I either need to know how to configure my dummy project to generate the md5/sha/metafile/... without having the source code - just have the .jar/sources.jar/javadoc.jar

OR I need to know how to configure my normal build to download the javadoc/sources withouth the correct .pom file

Comment: If you are OK with going back to the way modules were resolved prior to Gradle 6.0, it is possible. Take a look at the [this section of the user guide](https://docs.gradle.org/current/userguide/declaring_repositories.html#sec:supported_metadata_sources) (the important part is the `metadataSources { mavenPom(); artifact() } }` declaration).

Comment: this seems to work for me. jar AND sources are downloaded even with no pom or metadata file